# Get data from an asynchronous method?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I am having big time trouble with getting the data from my method `getAllPlayerData()` outside the `.then((Value)`.

The "bad print" in my code shows up before my "good print". I want to be able to use my variable "TheStats" in my code with all the data inside of it and not a "null" value or "instance of Future<Dynamic"

```
import 'package:cleanmaybe/Controllers/players_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PlayerStatView extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayerStatView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlayerStatView> createState() => _PlayerStatViewState();
}

class _PlayerStatViewState extends State<PlayerStatView> {
  var theStats;

  @override
  void initState() {

    getAllPlayerData().then((value) {
      theStats = value;
      print("Good print $theStats");
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("bad print $theStats");
    return Container();
  }
}
```

This is my "getAllPlayerData()"

```
getAllPlayerData() async{
  SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;
  int? id = sp.getInt('idPlayer');
  final statAccess = DatabaseModel();
  var lookForData = await statAccess.getPlayerData(id);
  return lookForData;
}
```

And if you need it, this is my `getPlayerData(id)` method that fetches all the data from my database:

```
Future getPlayerData(idPlayer) async {
    var dbCoach = await db;
    var dataPlayer = dbCoach!.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM players WHERE"
        " idPlayer = '$idPlayer'");
    return dataPlayer;
}
```

Comment: read about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget - it is designed for building your UI based on `Future` data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "bad print" will practically always run before "Good print" as long as `getAllPlayerData()` take any time at all to process with this construct.

There are several ways to handle this, but a suggestion is to use the `FutureBuilder` widget for it (as @pskink just wrote as a comment :)) Check the [offical documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).